# Jelastic netbeans plugin "unable to complete action .check your network connection"

Tags: netbeans, cloud, jelastic

I have downloaded the jelastic plugin for netbeans,and i have also logged in with the appropriate credentials provided from jelastic and added it to my netbeans cloud ,but if  i try to open myjelastic from netbeans cloud i get this error:

> Unable to complete action check your network connection

meanwhile my network connection is healthy.

Comment: could you please tell on which hoster this problem appears?

Comment: @Aless  "cloudhosting.rsaweb.co.za"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check what version of Jelastic your hosting provider runs. Since [Netbeans plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48045/jelastic-cloud-platform-integration) supports Jelastic up to 2.5

Comment: What's the server that you use now? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i am using [LayerShift](http://www.layershift.com/mylayershift)